# Как установить поштучное условие?

Tags: java

Есть код:

```
@SubscribeEvent
 public void onRenderPlayer(RenderPlayerEvent.Pre e){
        if(e.entityPlayer.inventory.hasItem(Items.emerald))
            e.setCanceled(true);

 }
```

где `if(e.entityPlayer.inventory.hasItem(Items.emerald))` отвечает за то, чтобы у игрока в инвертаре был предмет, в моем случае `emerald`.

Как сделать так, чтобы требование было не к 1 emerald, а к 6, например?

Comment: Для начала - это не javascript

Comment: @MnyE, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Это не javascript. Может, стоит попробовать так?

```
if(e.entityPlayer.inventory.hasItem(Items.emerald && Items.emerald2 && Items.emerald3))
```

Comment: Так не работает,возможно это java

Answer (score 1):

Это не JS и даже не ECMAScript (ну или эзотерическая поделка, о какой я не знаю).
Условие не полное, я не знаю функции по возврату количества предметов, но нужно примерно такое:

```
if(e.entityPlayer.inventory.hasItem(Items.emerald) && e.entityPlayer.inventory.count(Items.emerald) == 6) e.setCanceled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос к java не относящийся, а к api, который вы используете. Как я понял, это minectaft. Получайте ячейку, где лежит emerald и получайте число, сколько его в ячейке.

Comment: Да,это майнкрафт,но как сделать выше описаное я всеравно непонимаю.На 1 форуме сказали что нужно посчитать в цикле кол-во предметов

Answer (score 1):

В идеале, как мне кажется, если есть ячейка, то логично было иметь описание содержимого этой ячейки и с кол-вом, соответственно. Должно быть свойство, что ли, "Count()" или еще как-то, может. в цикле. Но "Count", мне кажется, должен быть - это логично.